# Same code running matplotlib thru anaconda prompt and spyder give images of different clarity

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to run a deep learning code. I usually run in spyder win10. The images obtained thru matplotlib are saved using something like:

```
plt.savefig('./output/'+filename+'_'+str(num)+'.png',dpi=360)
```

Occasionally, I would run the code thru the anaconda prompt using:

python abc.py

In this case, the image would appear on-screen. I realise that if I enlarge them, I can get a much clearer image with more details, as compared to the saved image. Why is this so? I have attached some images for comparison

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Note how the numbers appear to have different sizes in your examples. If the font sizes are the same, this means the figure size changed. Try adding this before your figure creation commands. `plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))`

Comment: Thanks K.Cl I added in but it's still the same.  If I run thru the anaconda prompt, the image would appear on screen and saved at the same time. If I saved the on screen fig directly, it shows a small image. If I enlarge it by maximizing and then saved, I get a much clearer image. The org saved image (360dpi) has the highest resolution. The 1st on screen image has the smallest while the maximized one is somewhere in between. Still don't understand why this happens.